# question from rohatgi

Tags: probability

A box contains $20 $ black and $30$ green balls. One ball at a time is drawn at random, its color is noted, and the ball is then replaced in the box for the next draw. 
Let $N$ be the trial at which the fifth green ball is drawn. Find the probability
that the fifth green ball is drawn on the nth draw. (Note that $N$ take values
$5,6,7,...$)

Comment: I think you might have mixed this question with this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298211/probability-question-from-rohatgi

Comment: I think $P(X=N)=\binom{N-1}{4} \cdot \left( \frac{30}{50} \right)^{5} \cdot \left( \frac{20}{50} \right)^{N-5}$

Comment: I´ve transferred your attempt to the right question. If you can comprehend the answer of automaticallyGenerated mark the answer as accepted $\left( \color{limegreen}{\checkmark} \right)$

Answer (score 2):

If the fifth green ball is picked on turn $n$, then the other $4$ need to be picked in the first $n-1$ turns. This means that we need to arrange a series of green and black balls of length $n-1$ with $4$ balls. The total ways to arrange this is $$\binom{n-1}{4}$$

This must be multiplied by the probability that each arrangement happens. This is equal to $$\left(\frac{30}{50}\right)^{5}\left(\frac{20}{50}\right)^{n-5}$$

This gives a final probability of $$\binom{n-1}{4}\left(\frac{30}{50}\right)^{5}\left(\frac{20}{50}\right)^{n-5}$$